# Don't change the position of the buttons on profile change

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, profile-edit

If you save profile settings, the position of the buttons will be changed. It is not the best user experience.

> [image]

Would be better from the UX side, if you don't change the buttons position after a click.

Comment: Not shown publicly :)

Comment: @alexolut nothing to hide)

Comment: I don't understand how this would improve UX? There isn't any situation where a user would need to click that button more than once at a time, so moving it isn't an inconvenience to anyone. Moving the button makes it more obvious that the save worked. Making it less obvious would only make it more likely users would keep clicking it for no reason. What does this change achieve?

Comment: @animuson "There isn't any situation where a user would need to click that button more than once at a time" it's more about UX consistency. "Moving the button makes it more obvious that the save worked" you show message, not need to move buttons. "Making it less obvious would only make" improving UX experience makes it less obvious?

Comment: It is common UX to manipulate buttons to emphasize that something worked. E.g. Google commonly changes them into weird animations. A lot of sites plainly remove the button from the page once it's been used, until you do something again that warrants it appearing again. Your argument here is that keeping it in the same place makes the UX more consistent. How does it do that? My argument is that it doesn't.